# Do MacBooks have scissor-switch keyboards yet (Feb 2020)?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I can't get a clear answer about this topic. According to the live chat support on the Apple Store website, the mid-2019 MacBook Air models do have the scissor-switch keyboard. However, every other source I check says they still have the butterfly keyboards until mid-2020.

Can I get a definitive answer about whether a new MacBook purchase in the US would have the previous butterfly style keyboard or the newly planned scissor-switch keyboard?

[image: chat support]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2019 MacBook Air uses the third-generation Butterfly keyboard.

This is also clearly stated on Apple's [marketing page](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/) for the 2019 MacBook Air:

> "The latest-generation MacBook Air keyboard features our butterfly mechanism [...]"

The new scissor-switch style keyboard debuted on the 16" MacBook Pro, which was released in November of 2019. The 2019 MacBook Air is from July of 2019.

It doesn't matter which country you buy your MacBook Air in. Different countries obviously have different keyboard in terms of number of keys and the letters on them - but they're all made in the same way. I.e. a Mid 2019 MacBook Air is going to have the same style of keyboard in every country.

There's no such thing as a "Mid 2020 MacBook Air" (yet). You can only speculate whether it will have a scissor-switch key, or the butterfly keyboard. The public does not know.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm set on buying any type of macbook with the scissor-switch style keyboard (whether air or pro). I'll place an order for the 16" MacBook Pro

Comment: @Maros I have one of the 16" MBP models and I'm sure you'll be ecstatic with it. However, if you would've originally been happy with a MacBook Air, then the 16" Pro is a huge upgrade in comparison and may not be necessary if all you're concerned about is the keyboard? If it helps, take a look at [Keyboard Service Program for MacBook, MacBook Air, and MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks) to see if that gives you any peace of mind. This basically covers you for 4 years after the initial purchase of the MacBook Air.

Comment: @Monomeeth I actually looked at that a while back and brought my MacBook Air in to have it examined. They ended up wanting to charge me over $300 to repair the keyboard. That's the point where I started looking around at alternatives. But reading your link again, it looks like the repair was supposed to be free? The other thing is I use the machine for development daily so I can't have it gone for days/weeks :(

Comment: @Maros Yes, being without your Mac for days/weeks is a real problem if you don't have another Mac you can use. :(